# C# Winform Change the type of row for data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, controls

There is a DataGridView component in C# Winform. It's easy to change the column type to checkbox or text. I wonder that how to change the row type like that?

I tried to find on the internet but there are no results. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Firstly, the control is named `DataGridView`. It is not the same thing as the `GridView` control, which isn't even for WinForms. Also, what has this question got to do with tooltips? Please apply relevant and only relevant tags to your question.

Comment: As for the question, the reason you can't find an answer to your question is that the question is nonsensical. Rows in a `DataGridView` don't have a type the way columns do.  The column type determines how the data in that column is displayed and edited. What do you think the type of a row would do, if such a thing existed? Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it. If what you want is to change the type of one specific cell then you can do that, but that's a cell operation. Of course, it could be done to each cell in a row.

Comment: For the record, if you did want to change the type of a cell, e.g. you have a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and you wanted one cell to be a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, you can do that like so: `myDataGridView[columnIndex, rowIndex] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();`. If you wanted to do that for a whole row, you could use a `for` loop to set the column index.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to "change the row type". Is there something you want displayed differently on a row-by-row basis?

Comment: Make all the columns in your datatable's datacolumns into bool type, and when the DGV autogenerates columns for them it will make it a combobox; you don't need to change the datagridviewcolumn type